# how to use imu_um7 in Ros?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,I want to use the imu_um7 in Ros,but i can only fiind the imu_um6 driver in ROS.
with IMU_UM7,it has the error as follow:

WARN] [1417851404.000159772]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1417851404.098578951]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
*****[ERROR] [1417851404.098967502]: Unable to set communication register.*****
[ INFO] [1417851404.099049411]: Attempting reconnection after error.
[ INFO] [1417851405.099778860]: Successfully connected to serial port.
[ WARN] [1417851405.198359615]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1417851405.296903714]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1417851405.395406947]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1417851405.493857153]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.
[ WARN] [1417851405.592298609]: Timed out waiting for packet from device.

any ideas for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199004/how-to-use-imu_um7-in-ros?/) by [linuxcumt](https://answers.ros.org/users/20971/linuxcumt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UM7 doesn't work with the UM6 driver, it's a different protocol. We investigated doing a "quick port" for the community, but discovered it wasn't a "quick port" sort of task.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-12-06**:
Adding to this answer, a colleague of mine has started that port in this [repo](https://github.com/mars-uoit/um7) based on the UM6 driver.  I believe it is functional but I am not completely aware of its state.  Give it a try.